# Equivalent API of SetupDiCallClassInstaller to uninstall my modem

Tags: windows, winapi, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, setupapi

I used `SetupDiCallClassInstaller` with `DIF_REMOVE` as parameter to uninstall my modem. But when I tested my application in "Windows 7" "64-Bit" machine I got error `0xE0000235`, But I couldnt found a solution to solve this.

Some of the [SO links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684061/setupdicallclassinstaller-throws-error-in-wow64-when-compiled-for-32-bit-on-a-64) which talks about this doesnt have a solution rather than creating a 64 bit exe, Which I dont want to.

My question here is is there any other API which do the same ( I want to un-install my modem )?

Comment: No, a 64-bit process is required.

Comment: No other solution for this? like using some other APIS?

Comment: No, there is no other solution. You'll need a 64-bit process. The question you linked to seems like it answers this pretty well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SetupDiCallClassInstaller throws ERROR_IN_WOW64 when compiled for 32 bit on a 64 bit machine.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684061/setupdicallclassinstaller-throws-error-in-wow64-when-compiled-for-32-bit-on-a-64), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685183/why-is-the-setupdicallclassinstaller-function-restricted-to-64-bit-programs